# how to prevent cell color to cover table's borders?

Tags: tables, colortbl

When I change the background color of a cell in a table, the color covers the borders, however I want the horizontal lines to remain. 
I have a simple command `\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}` in my table. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table cell color overlaps cell border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121476/table-cell-color-overlaps-cell-border)

Answer (score 4):

Please always provide a complete small example that demonstrates the problem. If the lines are from `\hline` then it is not supposed to happen. If they are from `\cline` then that is amdocumented feature and the `colortbl` documentation suggests that you try `\hhline` instead. With the amount of information in the question, it is impossible to say.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I had used \cline as below code, and replacing \hhline solved my problem.
\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline  1 &2 &\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}3
  \cline{2-3}
  \hline  4 &5 &\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}6
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Answer (score 0):

This could just be a PDF display "error".  This is what happened to me.  I thought the cell outlines were covered, but if you zoom in on your PDF or actually print the document, the original cell outlines are there!

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) has tools which have been designed to solve that kind of problem. With the tools of `nicematrix`, the rules won't seem to disappear, whatever PDF viewer and level of zoom you use.