# Table cell color overlaps cell border

Tags: tables, color

As the graphic and MWE below show, some of colored my table cells are obscured the cell colors. I'd appreciate help fixing this.

[image: Table with colored cells]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|cc|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & D & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-6} 
a & \cellcolor{blue!25} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & \cellcolor{red!25} \tabularnewline
\cline{2-3} 
b &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-4} 
c &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-5} 
d &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-6} 
e &  & \cellcolor{green!25} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-6} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cellcolor overwrites partial horizontal lines (\cline)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65231)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`hhline`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) here which simply adds vertical space and doesn’t get over-drawn by `\cellcolor`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|cc|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} &           D           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} \tabularnewline \hhline{~|*{5}{-}}
             a           &  \cellcolor{blue!25}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  &                       &  \cellcolor{red!25}   \tabularnewline \cline{2-3}
             b           &                       &                       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  &                       &  \tabularnewline \cline{2-4}
             c           &                       &                       &                       &                       &  \tabularnewline \cline{2-5}
             d           &                       &                       &                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \tabularnewline \hhline{~|*5-}
             e           &                       & \cellcolor{green!25}  &                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \tabularnewline \hhline{~|*5-}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for me. The borders are still overlapped when I try the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of the package `nicematrix` has tools design to address that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[first-row,first-col,hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{blue!25}{1-1}
  \cellcolor{red!25}{1-5}
  \cellcolor{green!25}{5-2}
\Body
  & A & B & C & D & E \\
a &   & \Block{1-*}{} & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block{3-1}{} & \Block{4-1}{} \\
b &   &   & \Block{1-*}{} \\
c &   &   &   & \Block{1-*}{} \\
d &   &   &   &   & \Block{1-*}{} \\
e \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]