# [table, xcdraw]{xcolor} table with {adjustbox}: color overwrites horizontal lines

Tags: tables, color, multirow, adjustbox

I have the following table; for some reason the coloured cells make some horizontal cell lines to be overwritten. I have tried `hhline` (as posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/cellcolor-overwrites-partial-horizontal-lines-cline) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121476/table-cell-color-overlaps-cell-border)) solution, but the problem still appears. Is there a way to solve this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf} 
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={\textheight},keepaspectratio}%
\begin{tabular}{l|l|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{9AFF99}}l |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{9AFF99}}l |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}}c |}
\cline{2-5}
                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}Through Analytic fgfdtrewsaxdc}                                                                & Through fgttfgdvfgt program                                                                                              \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & Tabcvfghdtj (K)       & P ab cvfgtfdrfgtr (CTg) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Do they really\\ intersect?\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}P of thsklnfghtyof (CTg)\\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Without ABC}   & 0.0000000000000       & 1.8768983712859         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.6254763820172                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Including ABC} & 0.0000000000000       & 1.9978304528583         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Yes. Thus, this value\\ is exact\end{tabular}                                         & 2.1920234810483                                                                                                          \\ \hline
                                    & 10.0000000000000      & 2.0076820015184         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Yes. Thus, this value\\ is exact\end{tabular}                                         & 2.1878908337066                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 30.1000000000000      & 2.0105474499721         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Yes. Thus, this value\\ is exact\end{tabular}                                         & 2.1571656024016                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 50.2000000000000      & 2.0361883797375         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Yes. Thus, this value\\ is exact\end{tabular}                                         & 2.1105384349108                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 70.3000000000000      & 2.0637913576613         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 2.0496063553815                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 90.4000000000000      & 2.0890743023491         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.9964447103662                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 110.5100000000000     & 2.1374242884938         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.9414064990460                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 130.6100000000000     & 2.1802324702746         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.8996473430987                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 150.7100000000000     & 2.2277408433265         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.8535292651023                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 170.8100000000000     & 2.2724174008773         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.8112793074126                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 190.9100000000000     & 2.3370794057247         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.7768519603870                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 211.0100000000000     & 2.4019136100316         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.7281770187307                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 231.1100000000000     & 2.4966115632576         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.7021655083759                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 251.2100000000000     & 2.5960230538900         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.6691805546782                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 271.3100000000000     & 2.7221124247251         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.6327729684592                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 291.4100000000000     & 2.8023914311475         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.6005950869819                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 311.5200000000000     & 3.0130911293214         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.5654334465555                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 331.6200000000000     & 3.2658768278108         &                                                                                                                  & 1.5256329248605                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 351.7200000000000     & 3.3648792552416         &                                                                                                                  & 1.4917803567779                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 371.8200000000000     & 3.1541485780113         &                                                                                                                  & 1.4786501581343                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 391.9200000000000     & 3.4583419699743         &                                                                                                                  & 1.4319894888515                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 412.0200000000000     & 2.7546822691315         &                                                                                                                  & 1.3917076062501                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 432.1200000000000     & 3.0356970295513         &                                                                                                                  & 1.4282838144890                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 452.2200000000000     & 2.6418159833017         &                                                                                                                  & 1.3884510003364                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 472.3200000000000     & 2.7646791008881         &                                                                                                                  & 1.3506422754923                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 492.4200000000000     & 2.6095474501685         &                                                                                                                  & 1.3087755076084                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 512.5300000000000     & 2.4417568550597         &                                                                                                                  & 1.3026095611169                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 532.6300000000000     & 2.4360512892481         &                                                                                                                  & 1.2545525686739                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 552.7300000000000     & 2.2806580727298         &                                                                                                                  & 1.2183131727897                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 572.8300000000000     & 2.1847925993616         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  & 1.2029395755417                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 592.9299999999999     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 613.0300000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 633.1300000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 653.2300000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 673.3300000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 693.4299999999999     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 713.5400000000000     &                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 733.6400000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 753.7400000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 773.8400000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 793.9400000000001     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 814.0400000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 834.1400000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 854.2400000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 874.3400000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 894.4400000000001     &                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 914.5500000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 934.6500000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 954.7500000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 974.8500000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 994.9500000000000     &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 1015.0500000000000    &                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No. Thus, this value\\ is overestimated\end{tabular}                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 1035.1500000000001    &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 1055.2500000000000    &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 1075.3499999999999    &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                    & 1095.4500000000000    &                         &                                                                                                                  &                                                                                                                          \\ \cline{2-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{aa}
\label{ff}
\end{table}
```

Comment: colortbl explicitly documents that it does not support `\cline`. Do you really needs lines and colour?

Comment: You can redraw the lines later. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303819/pdflatex-output-of-rasterized-pdf-due-to-faulty-table-lines/303859#303859 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409650/line-problem-when-use-color-table/409657#409657

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your comment. If I remove `\usepackage{colortbl}`, the problem still appears - see edit

Comment: Actually, it seems to be only a pdf viewer issue. In your very code I can see the horizontal lines using Pdf XChange Editor, though the internal viewer of TexStudio doesn't show them.

Comment: no the table colouring is being done by colortbl, (the xcolor package loads colortbl)

Comment: @bmv no, if the colour overlaps `\hline` it is a viewer issue, but `\cline` takes no vertical space, it is surrounded by negative space and so the coloured panels are explicitly drawn over the rule.

Comment: try to use `hhline` package and its lines.