# How to prevent the borders of colored cell from disappear

Tags: tables, color

the borders of the colored cells disappear in low size and appear when zooming in. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.8} A & B & C & D      & E\\
                             &          &       & number1 & number2\\\hline
                          10 &       20 &    30 &         20 & 10\\
                             &          &    15 &            &  8\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I want the upper horizontal line to appear. But the result is as shown here..
[image]

i know it is a duplicate question [how to prevent cell color to cover table's borders?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76146/how-to-prevent-cell-color-to-cover-tables-borders), but the solutions provided didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I used `\hline` instead of `\cline` and still the same result."the upper border disappear"

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, but i do not know which package you use. For more help, please make minimal working example with \documentclass{..}\usepackage{...}\begin{document} ... your code ... \end{document}

Comment: Well, use `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}` to increase the thickness of rules in a table.

Comment: the lines are thin to start with and you are making them only 65% of that, just use thicker lines. Also you have spurious white space into the left and right of your tabular, in the box due to missing `%` at ends of lines.

Comment: @Zarko Edited ...

Comment: On my system with your MWE, there is no difference between the width of the rules around the colored cells and the width of the rules around "normal" cells.

Comment: This is just an artefact of the viewer. Voting to close.

Comment: @Werner i tried \hhline{} but in vain.

Comment: @Misaki: You don't show what you've tried, so we don't know why it doesn't work for you. Moreover, as I mentioned, this is a viewer-related mis-representation. When you zoom in, are the lines visible?

Comment: Yes they are visible but with a large zoom in